# How to Write Kotlin Unit Test with kotlin-test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kotlin

I am trying to test my code using Kotlin. When trying to import the `kotlin.test` package, nothing appears.

Do I have to add the dependency somewhere first? And how can I run my unit test afterwards?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `kotlin.test` package is packaged in `kotlin-test` module, so you need add the dependencies in your `build.gradle` as below:

```
dependencies{
   testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Beside that, you need to add an unit test framework in the `build.gradle` like as `junit-4`, for example:

```
dependencies{
   testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
}
```

How to write a JUnit Test? you can see it in [junit.org](http://junit.org/junit4/) as further.

Comment: I am currently not in AndroidStudio, so there is no build.gradle file.I simply created a standard IntelliJ Kotlin JVM project.

Comment: @Rechunk download the jars of the [junit4](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar) and [kotlin-test](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.jetbrains.kotlin%22%20AND%20a%3A%22kotlin-test%22) from maven repository, and then add them as libraries in your intellij project.

Answer (score 0):

This is now well outlined on the [Kotlin Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-test-using-junit.html#add-the-code-to-test-it) on how to set-up *Jetbrains Kotlin Test JUnit* on `Intellij` using *Kotlin DSL*.

**Step 1 - Add this line to your dependencies** i.e. inside `build.gradle.kts`  file

```
dependencies { 
...

testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
...

}
```

**Step 2 Add the test task block** i.e. inside `build.gradle(.kts)`  file:

```
  tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Otherwise, try using  this dependency with the latest Kotlin Version. For me this was `Kotlin version 1.9.10`.

```
testImplementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlinVersion")
```